# "Bookmarks are being synced..." message in Safari

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, bookmarks

What causes the iPad to show

> Bookmarks are being synced. Please add the bookmarks once syncing has completed

when attempting to add a bookmark or favorite in Safari and how can it be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

Your iPad or any iOS/macOS device logged into an iCloud with Safari sharing in `Settings -> iCloud -> Safari` will sync history, bookmarks, and logins. Any changes to the bookmarks will trigger the sync, forcing you to wait. Its a pain in the arse to manage bookmarks with this always popping up.

Disable the syncing in your iCloud settings under Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of iCloud! You can either turn off iCloud bookmark sync

or

I am not sure it can be done for individual bookmarks, I believe it is a system wide setting.